# Ionic/angular how to chang stylesheet link tag on radio button click event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I have been trying to figure out how swap stylesheets when a user clicks on my settings tap but not having any luck so far.

I am able to store the selected stylesheet in my local storage using ngstorage but the link tag is not updating. Here is my code for the link tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="starter">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link ng-href="css/{{theme}}.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/truncate.js"></script>
      <script src="js/ngStorage.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
      <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/posts.js"></script>
      <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
      <script src="js/filter.js"></script>
      <script src="js/truncate.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
       <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then my radio button is below together with my controller code.

```
<script id="display-settings-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-modal-view>
        <ion-header-bar class="nav-title-slide-ios7 bar-reactor">
            <h1 class="title">Default Text Size</h1>
            <div class="buttons close-button">
                <button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-close-empty" ng-click="closeModal()"></button>
            </div>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
            <form action="." ng-submit="noSubmit($event)">
              <ion-radio ng-model="data.font_size" ng-value="'larger-fonts'" ng-click="save_settings('larger-fonts')">X-Large</ion-radio>
              <ion-radio ng-model="data.font_size" ng-value="'big-fonts'" ng-click="save_settings('big-fonts')">Large</ion-radio>
              <ion-radio ng-model="data.font_size" ng-value="''" ng-click="save_settings('')">Medium</ion-radio>
              <ion-radio ng-model="data.font_size" ng-value="'small-fonts'" ng-click="save_settings('small-fonts')">Small</ion-radio>
            </form>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-modal-view>
</script>
```

My controller is

```
.controller("SettingsCtrl", function($scope, $state, $ionicModal, $localStorage) {
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('display-settings-modal.html', {
            scope: $scope,
            animation: 'slide-in-up'
        }).then(function(modal) {
            $scope.displayhmodal = modal;
            $scope.modal = modal;
        });
        $scope.openDisplayModal = function() {
            $scope.displayhmodal.show();
        };
        $scope.closeModal = function() {
            $scope.modal.hide();
        };
        //Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
        $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            $scope.modal.remove();
        });
        // Execute action on hide modal
        $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
            // Execute action
        });
        // Execute action on remove modal
        $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
            // Execute action
        });

        $scope.data = {
            font_size: ''
        }

        $scope.save_settings = function( data ) {
            $localStorage.theme_data = data;
            $scope.theme = $localStorage.theme;
            console.log($scope.theme)
        }

})
```

How can i change the stylesheet_link_tag to display the selected theme

```
<link ng-href="css/{{theme}}.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the theme property on the $rootScope:

```
.controller("SettingsCtrl", function($scope, $state, $ionicModal, $localStorage, $rootScope) {
   .....
   $scope.save_settings = function( data ) {
        $localStorage.theme_data = data;
        $rootScope.theme = $localStorage.theme;
        console.log($rootScope.theme)
    }
```

Comment: This works thanks. but do you know why ng storage deletes values on page refresh.

Comment: hmm this is strange.. its hard to tell without seeing all of the code

Comment: It the exact same code i am using but when i do a page refresh, the ` $localStorage.theme_data = data;` but when i refresh the page it rootscope returns to nulll. meaning the data is not persistent.

Comment: if i understand correctly, try setting the value when the controller inits: `$rootScope.theme = $localStorage.theme;`. on the first line of controller function for example

Comment: also, shouldnt it be $localStorage.theme = data ?